# How to get the radio Button value in the next page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a label and two radio buttons, i am using post method to and trying to get the value of the radio button but i have no clue to do it

```
 <div class="input-group">
                <label>Enter Your Age</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
 <div class="input-group">
                <label>Select Your Gender</label>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" Text="Male" Checked="True" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" Text="Female" />
            </div>
 <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" PostBackUrl="~/receivePage.aspx" OnClick="submit_Click" />
```

and in my receive page

```
 String age = ((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("txtAge")).Text;
```

this gives me the age value but how do I get the radio buttons value ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<div class="input-group">
            <label>Select Your Gender</label>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" Text="Male" Checked="True" value="Male" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" Text="Female" value="Female" />
        </div>
```

You need to state a value for each radio button.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RadioButtonList instead of two separate RadioButtons:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblGender" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Selected="True" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Female" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

In code-behind, you could get the SelectedValue of the list:

```
String gender = ((RadioButtonList)PreviousPage.FindControl("rblGender")).SelectedValue;
```